# Error: Unexpected `storiesOf` usage: C:/Users/imran/react-package/src/stories/Requirements.stories.js (line 6, col 16)

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook, npm-package

Unable to index ./src/stories/Requirements.stories.js:

Error: Unexpected `storiesOf` usage: C:/Users/imran/react-package/src/stories/Requirements.stories.js (line 6, col 16).

In SB7, we use the next-generation `storyStoreV7` by default, which does not support `storiesOf`.
More info, with details about how to opt-out here:

```
import React from "react";
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react";

import { Requirements } from "../components/Requirements";

const stories = storiesOf('App Test', module);

stories.add('App', () => {
    return (<Requirements />)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're seeing is related to the usage of `storiesOf`, which is not supported in Storybook 7 with the next-generation `storyStoreV7`. Storybook 7 introduced some changes in the way stories are defined and managed, and it no longer uses `storiesOf`. Instead, it encourages using the new syntax for defining stories.

To resolve this issue and update your stories to work with Storybook 7, you should refactor your story definitions using the new syntax. Here's an example of how you can update your code:

```
// Import your component
import React from 'react';
import { ComponentName } from '../components/Assistant';

// Export a default export named 'default' (if applicable)
export default {
  title: 'Assistant', // Define the title for your stories
  component: ComponentName, // Specify the component being used in the stories
};

// Define your stories using the 'args' pattern
export const App = (args) => <ComponentName {...args} />;

// Optionally, provide default values for your component props
App.args = {
  // Define your component's props here
};
```

Here's what you need to do:

1. Import your component.
2. Export a default object that includes the `title` (the storybook title), `component` (the component being used), and your individual story definitions.
3. Define your stories using the `args` pattern, where `args` can be used to provide default values for your component props.

Replace `ComponentName` with the actual name of your component.

This updated code aligns with the new way of defining stories in Storybook 7. Make sure to apply this pattern to all your stories, and it should resolve the issue you're facing.